# How can I overload static methods that take in a base class or its derived classes in C++?

Tags: c++

Here's a bit of context:

```cpp
struct Element { /* ... */ };

struct Expr : public Element { /* ... */ };

struct NumberExpr : public Expr { /* ... */ };

struct BinaryExpr : public Expr {
    std::unique_ptr<Expr> lhs;
    /* ... */
};

/* and many more AST nodes... */

class CodeGenerator {
    /* ... */
    static llvm::Value* generate(std::unique_ptr<Element> element) { /* ... */ }

    static llvm::Value* generate(std::unique_ptr<Expr> element) { /* ... */ }

    static llvm::Value* generate(std::unique_ptr<NumberExpr> element)

    static llvm::Value* generate(std::unique_ptr<BinaryExpr> element) {
        // Problem here!!
        auto lhs = generate(std::move(element->lhs));

        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Currently, the problematic line will `generate(std::unique_ptr<Expr> element)` for everything, even if `element` is `std::unique_ptr<NumberExpr>`. I understand that this behaviour is by design, but I want to ask how I can implement the expected behaviour that the 'most related' overloaded methods should be used (by 'most related', I mean use the exact class, if unavailable, use its base class `Expr` (if inherited from it) or `Element` (the top-level base class)

I think this sounds like a `function template` problem, but I have never learned/used templates before so I'm a bit stuck; however, I don't mind solution in templates. Thank you.

P.s: I believe one solution is to put `generate` as a virtual method of `Element`, but this defeats the whole point of isolating the algorithm from the object.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks, just to clarify, does it mean I have to use `virtual` or there is another way involving function templates?

Comment: It's weird to return a pointer, and It's weird to force your free functions to take a `unique_ptr` as their argument instead of just a (possibly `const`) reference. But then it also seems like this already is something that should just be a virtual member function and I don't understand your reason for not writing one.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thanks, the reason I use pointers at all is to integrate with LLVM. And also I don't want to use `virtual` because I'm trying to implement visitor pattern. But if there aren't any other ways, I guess I'll use `virtual`.